# Upgrade expo sdk should ios/android files be updated automatically?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, upgrade

What is the proposed workflow when upgrading to expo sdk 48 from 46 and you have ios/android folders (e.g. used npx expo prebuild previously)?

I'm not sure if I've done something wrong with my setup, or are you supposed to have to manually change build.gradle for android and the Podfile for ios for it to work?

I did this:

- yarn add expo@^48.0.0
- npx expo install --fix
- npx expo doctor
- npx expo prebuild (this changed some files but neither of podfile/build.gradle)
- npx expo run:android (got some errors here) <-- this was solved by upgrading build.gradle version, and the build/compile/target version
- when running npx expo:run:ios I get error [!] Invalid Podfile file: 767 unexpected token
  config = use_native_modules!

Which I have not solved yet.

But yeah, main concern - should this be updated automatically when upgrading or is it correct workflow to manually fix these stuff?
Also if we check the react-native-upgrader aloooot of stuff is changed in the ios/android-folders which has not been touched by the npx expo prebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Your project is a bare workflow and needs some add different changes as the [Expo SDK 48 article](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-48-ccb8302e231) says. Beyond the steps you did, look at [these additional steps for bare workflow projects](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-48-ccb8302e231#:%7E:text=If%20you%20manage%20your%20own%20native%20projects%20(bare%20workflow)).

Comment: Edit: sorry in advance for no formatting, but comments seem to not have them. 

You can use prebuild without actually permanently ejecting from the managed workflow. 
It's also stated in the article. But they do not state what more I need to do when running prebuild and upgrading the SDK.

If you manage your own native projects (bare workflow):
— Apply any relevant changes from the React Native Upgrade Helper.
— Alternatively, you could consider adopting prebuild for easier upgrades in the future.